# Optimize mysql recursive join query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query-optimization, self-join

I have two tables `ps_product` and `ps_category`. The product table has somewhere around 146690 rows in local db and 196000 in remote db, with `btree` index on `id_product` and `id_default_category`. The category table has some 851 rows and `btree` index on `id_category` and `id_parent` columns.

The categories are hierarchical upto 6 levels and I need all the products with all their categories. So if product 53 is of category 67 which in turn is a subcategory of 50 which is a subcategory of 43... and so on all the way up to 1, which is the root category, I will get **53**->67->50->43->20->1->null.

I have figured out a mysql query which makes a self join to `ps_category` 6 times to fetch the data and it takes approximately **0.8 secs** on local db and - **5 sec** over network to execute. Is there any way I can optimise it? The query:

```
    SELECT 
    p.id_product, c.id_category, c1.id_category, c2.id_category, c3.id_category, c4.id_category, c5.id_category, c6.id_category
FROM `ps_category` c
    left join ps_product p on p.id_category_default = c.id_category
    left join ps_category c1 on c1.id_category = c.id_parent  
    left join ps_category c2 on c2.id_category = c1.id_parent  
    left join ps_category c3 on c3.id_category = c2.id_parent  
    left join ps_category c4 on c4.id_category = c3.id_parent
    left join ps_category c5 on c5.id_category = c4.id_parent  
    left join ps_category c6 on c6.id_category = c5.id_parent
```

Comment: 0.8 micro second is very fast. Why are you looking for a more optimised solution at all?

Comment: @Shadow, changed the stats

Comment: your query is fine for what you want and can hardly be optimized  better. Depending on your application (how often new products are added to the database), you can set up a MATERIALIZED VIEW. The concept doesnt exists in MySQL but you can "mimick" it: Check this http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views

Comment: you can compute the self joins manually by program to avoid your 5-6 self join.(Using associative array)

Comment: Let's see the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: The query returns 146K rows?  Won't that swamp the client?

Comment: Which Engine?  What are the `PRIMARY KEYs`?  Better yet, add `CREATE TABLE` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

One option to try is the use of a closure table.

```
CREATE TABLE category_closure (
    `a_catagory_id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `d_category_id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`a_category_id`,`d_category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

This table records the relationships between the various levels of categories in the hierarchy. The `a_category_id` refers to the ancestor in a relationship, while the `d_category_id` refers to the descendant.

For the table to work properly, each category must be entered into the table as its own ancestor and descendant.

```
INSERT INTO category_closure
(a_category_id, d_category_id)
SELECT
id_category,
id_category
FROM ps_category
```

Then you can enter your known relationships from the `id_parent` column on each category.

```
INSERT INTO category_closure
(a_category_id, d_category_id)
SELECT
id_parent,
id_category
FROM ps_category
WHERE id_parent IS NOT NULL
```

Finally, you need to connect the dots. Run the following SELECT in a `do..while` loop, and so long as rows are returned from it, insert those rows into the closure table and continue the loop.

```
SELECT
cc1.a_category_id,
cc2.d_category_id
FROM category_closure cc1
INNER JOIN category_closure cc2
ON cc2.a_category_id = cc1.d_category_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN category_closure missing_cc
ON missing_cc.a_category_id = cc1.a_category_id
AND missing_cc.d_category_id = cc2.d_category_id
WHERE missing_cc.a_category_id IS NULL
```

What this query does is it takes all existing relations, and finds what should also be present. For example, you have the following chain:

53 > 67 > 50

That means you'll have the following records, from the first two INSERTs:
(50,50)
(67,67)
(53,53)
(50,67)
(67,53)
(and others).

Now, what we need is (50,53), since 53 is an descendant of 50. In the SELECT query above, `cc1` will match the (50,67) record. `cc2` will match the (67,53) record. That means `missing_cc` is attempting to match up with 50 from `cc1` (the `a_category_id`) and 53 from `cc2` (the `d_category_id`).

Since initially no such record exists, the SELECT statement will return those two rows, you can insert them, and repeat. This time, going further up the chain. No need for you (or your program) to know how many layers there are, just continue until the SELECT finds no more results.

Finally, once your closure table is built, you can SELECT the relevant information:

```
SELECT 
p.id_product,
c.id_category,
GROUP_CONCAT(cc.a_category_id) AS parent_category_ids
FROM ps_category c
LEFT OUTER JOIN ps_product p
ON p.id_category_default = c.id_category
LEFT OUTER JOIN category_closure cc
ON cc.d_category_id = c.id_category
AND cc.a_category_id != c.id_category
GROUP BY c.id_category, p.id_product
```

This will select all categories, all products in each category, and then provide a comma separated list of the ancestor categories for each of those combinations.

Now, that's actually quite a bit of repeated information, since you could just run the categories and their ancestor's separately from the products, but it really boils down to how you intend to use this data, as to whether you can separate the queries or not.

Note: If you are adding and removing categories, you will have to repeat this process each time you do so, after deleting all the current closure entires. There are better ways to do this than shown here, and such ways can even allow you to drop the use of the `id_parent` column (especially if the hierarchy is non-cyclical), but such things are outside the scope of this question.

This answer should at least be able to let you try something, without having to change your application or any existing data.